# Replacing subselects with rank

Tags: sql, postgresql

Apologies for terrible title, I can't think of a better way to convey it right now.

My simplified problem is as follows;

- Imagine readings being entered into a table daily.
- A reading can either be Good, or Bad.
- A reading has a timestamp.

What I need is for the bad readings, retrieve the last known good reading and the next good reading.

A trivial way of doing this is to use sub selects;

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP AS badreading
    ,(
        SELECT TIMESTAMP
        FROM dailyreading dailyreading_2
        WHERE dailyreading_2.result = 'Good'
            AND dailyreading_2.TIMESTAMP < dailyreading.TIMESTAMP
        ORDER BY dailyreading_2.TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1
        ) previousGoodReading
    ,(
        SELECT TIMESTAMP
        FROM dailyreading dailyreading_2
        WHERE dailyreading_2.result = 'Good'
            AND dailyreading_2.TIMESTAMP > dailyreading.TIMESTAMP
        ORDER BY dailyreading_2.TIMESTAMP ASC LIMIT 1
        ) nextGoodReading
FROM dailyreading
WHERE result = 'Bad' `
```

SQL Fiddle here;

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3aedd/10

But this is painfully slow with my (fairly large) dataset. I have a feeling I could be doing this by using one of the ranking features of postgresql, but I can't get my head around it because I do not know how many consecutive bad readings there are before I get a good reading.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `lead()` and `lag()`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this better?

```
SELECT d1.timestamp as badreading
    ,  max(case when d2.timestamp < d1.timestamp then d2.timestamp end) as x
    ,  min(case when d2.timestamp > d1.timestamp then d2.timestamp end) as y  
FROM dailyreading d1, dailyreading d2
WHERE d1.result = 'Bad'
  AND d2.result = 'Good'
GROUP BY d1.timestamp
ORDER BY d1.timestamp;
```